# Changing python indexes in a string

Tags: python, string, indexing

I have the following problem:

Let's say s = 'ab'. len(s) = 2. it has 2 indexes: 0 and 1. What I want to do is to make ab of length 1, or have an index of 0.

All help is welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question can be answered two ways:

```
>>> s = 'ab'
>>> s = s[:1]
>>> s
'a'
```

or you want string stored in collection

```
>>> s = 'ab'
>>> s = (s,)
>>> s[0]
'ab'

>>> s = 'ab'
>>> s = [s]
>>> s[0]
'ab'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question then I guess you're looking for slicing:

```
>>> s = 'ab'
>>> s = s[:1]
>>> s
'a'
```

**Update:**

You need a list to do that.

```
>>> d ='abcefg'
>>> it = iter(d)
>>> d = [x + next(it) for x in it] #creates a list
>>> d
['ab', 'ce', 'fg']
>>> d[0]
'ab'
>>> d[1]
'ce'
>>> d[2]
'fg'
```

Another way using `zip`:

```
>>> d ='abcefg'
>>> it = iter(d)
>>> [x+y for x,y in zip(it,it)]
['ab', 'ce', 'fg']
```

Comment: not quiet, for example d ='abcefg'. What I want is d[0] = 'ab', d[1] = 'ce', d[2] = [fg].

Comment: @IsaacAltair add such examples in your question, I've updated my solution.

Comment: We are not allowed to use lists in our assignment, but it is great to come to know various solutions. thanks = D

Comment: @IsaacAltair You can't do that with a string, in a string an index points to only a single character.

Comment: @IsaacAltair what is `print_board`? This has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: Sorry, I posted print_board in a wrong thread. but thank you for your help.